# How do i implement a Jbutton and event listener to close the application?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, event-listener

The following is my code...the jButton would be added in the GuI method. I need a jbutton to add to the container and an eventlistener to enable the application to close when pushed.

```
public class BeetsWk1 extends JFrame{

public BeetsWk1(){

     GuI();
}

public void GuI(){
      FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout();

        layout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.CENTER);

    Container container;
    container = getContentPane();
    container.setBackground(new Color(052,062,138));
    container.setLayout(layout);

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setText ("Hello World" );
    label.setSize( 500, 400);
            label.setFont( new Font( "SanSerif", Font.PLAIN, 15) );
            label.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
    label.setForeground(Color.white);
    container.add( label );
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
            Dimension dimension = new Dimension(500, 500);
                        BeetsWk1 window = new BeetsWk1();
                       window.setVisible(true);
                        window.setSize(dimension);
                           window.setDefaultCloseOperation(window.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private Dimension Dimension(int i, int j) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: `label.setSize( 500, 400);`--> don't ever call `setSize/setXXXSize` on any component. Leave all that work to `LayoutManager's`. If somebody invites you to use `setSize/setXXXSize` or suggests to use Absolute-layout/null-layout: run away from that advice (it's about the worst one can give in Swing, these are considered as the root of all evil ;-))

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Guillaume! I am super new to java. How would I use the layout manager to set the layout? If I am going to have different components in my contentPane, how do I set the size of each of them in my layout manager? What layout managers do you find the most useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's stopping you?

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.setText("Some text");
getContentPane().add(button);

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           System.exit(0);
      }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just started java and adding an event listener is very new to me (I come from a web developement php/javascript background.

Answer (score 2):

```
// 'this' represents the frame
// the 'button' is provided free
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close your container then

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       @Override 
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);//jframe is your JFrame Object
      }
});
```

or if you want to close the total application then

```
system.exit(0);
```

Comment: 1) Note that the first suggestion will not have any immediate (visible) effect.  The user needs to click the `x` in the frame to have it take effect. 2) Will kill ever other GUI element at the same time, and also any non-daemon threads.